# Nexus 9 Landscape Resource

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm looking for what the correct landscape resource should be for the Nexus 9? It's currently picking up layout-sw720dp for portrait, however when it attempts to use layout-sw720dp-land it looks terrible. Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Check out this post for ARC Welder setup using the Nexus 9 layout folders, which shows how to convert the apk into an app that runs using the Chrome browser in MacOS, Windows, and Linux http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528670/emulate-arc-welder-in-android-studio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html

> The Nexus 9 is a premium 8.9” tablet with a screen size of 2048 x 1536
>   pixels (288 ppi), which translates to 1024 x 768 dip. This is a 4:3
>   aspect ratio, which is unique compared to earlier tablets.

so targeting the n9,

- layout-sw768dp for generic layouts on the n9 (and compatible devices)
- layout-sw1024dp-land for landscape
- layout-sw768dp-port for portrait

I haven't tried this personally,  but these should also work if you want to only target the n9

- layout-h1024dp-w768dp-port
- layout-w1024dp-h768dp-land

Helpful reading on qualifiers, http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers

Comment: First, thanks for the writeup and the suggested links, appreciate it! After a little trial and error, layout-sw720dp-land ended up working for landscape. Any idea why layout-sw1024dp-land wouldn't work?

Comment: Glad it helped you! :) Can you accept the answer?

perhaps its an ordering issue, try `layout-land-sw1024dp` ?

Comment: I tried both `layout-sw1024dp-land` and the couple `layout-w1024dp-h768dp-land` `layout-h1024dp-w768dp-port`  none of them works. The qualifier `layout-sw768dp` is the only that works fine

Comment: Which layout folders i need to create for Nexus 9 and Nexus 10 devices?